# Почему после выполнения Add_Point() меняется Bezier[number] и как это можно исправить?

Tags: c#

```
PointF[] Points = new PointF[50];
Bezier[] Bez = new Bezier[10];
int number = 0;

private void Add_Curve(object sender, EventArgs e)   
{          
    Bez[number] = new Bezier(Points, stepen);   
}
private void Add_Point(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Points[koltochek - 1] = e.Location;
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Массивы передаются по ссылке.

Нужно сделать копию массива. Тогда изменения значений в копии не будут влиять на оригинал.

```
Bez[number] = new Bezier(Points.ToArray(), stepen);
```

При этом подразумевается, что `PointF` - структура (значимый тип).

Comment: Спасибо большое! Теперь работает